# InsertCursor error

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to load data from a csv file (that contains well_id, x, y, elevation)  to a shapefile. In my script, it adds fields from the csv field header that is not in the shapefile. It then updates existing well_id, and add well_id that does not exist.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import csv,arcpy,codecs,ast 
csvfile = r'\\Cd1001-f18\gis\Clients\Enbridge\Line4_MP66_75\Project_Data\Table\mw_bh_loc_20171115.csv'

fc = r'Q:\Clients\Enbridge\Line4_MP66_75\Project_Data\bh_mw_loc.shp'

with codecs.open(csvfile,'rb',encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvFile:

    csvheader1 = [x.strip() for x in next(csvFile).split(',')]
    print csvheader1
    for row in csv.reader(csvFile):
        print row

gdbFields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
insertList = []

for x in range (0,len(csvheader1)):
    insertList.append('csvrow['+str(x)+']')
insertList.append('(float(csvrow[1]),float(csvrow[2]))')
csvheader2 = list(csvheader1)
csvheader2.append("SHAPE@XY")
insertList2 = tuple(csvheader2)

print csvheader2

newFields = [x for x in csvheader1 if x not in gdbFields]
print newFields
for x in newFields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc,x,'TEXT','','','200')
gdbNewFields = gdbFields + newFields
insertFields = csvheader1.append("SHAPE@XY")
fcWellIDValues = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "Well_ID")]
print fcWellIDValues
csvDict = csv.DictReader(codecs.open(csvfile, encoding ="utf-8-sig"))
for csvrow in csvDict:


    if csvrow["Well_ID"] in fcWellIDValues:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, gdbNewFields) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                if row["Well_ID"] == csv["Well_ID"]:
                    for x in newFields:
                        row[x] == csvrow[x]
                    cursor.updateRow(row)

    elif csvrow["Well_ID"] not in fcWellIDValues:
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc,csvheader2)as cursor:
            cursor.insertRow([insertList2])

print "done"
```

I am getting an error on the insertcursor.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlaw\Desktop\Application\csv_mwloader.py", line 47, in <module>
    cursor.insertRow([insertList2])
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

Comment: This seems to be your whole code rather than a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers).  Try printing your two variables `csvheader2` and `insertList2`.  If they are not lists of the same length then that will explain the error message.

Comment: You seem to be using `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` with `arcpy.InsertCursor` syntax. DataAcess is list-oriented, not dictionary-fueled.

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Vince I really appreciate it! I will fix up my syntax and see how it goes :D